# Why does a grid column contained in a borderless window have a ActualWidth less than that of the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have defined a window as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Margin="0"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="label"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Using the label to visualize what happens when I resize the window, I see that the grid column ActualWidth is 14 less than the MainForm.ActualWidth. Why is this? I have a similar application in which the discrepancy is 16.

```
label.Content = String.Format("Column width: {0} | Form width: {1}", MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, this.ActualWidth);
```

Comment: padding on the window?

Comment: The window width/height represent the overall window size, but the grid only occupies the client area of the window. The non-client area (caption & borders) sits between the two. If `Window.ResizeMode` allows resizing, then you will get some sort of border even if `Window.WindowStyle` is set to `None`.

Comment: Is this a named property or is it just there?

Answer (score 0):

If you investigate a live visual tree you can see that there is quite many items rendered for you. Each of them takes up some space. You can investigate properties of the items to see the details:

[image]

You can also compare the results for both of your applications and see where the difference is coming from.